# Which is the Recommended variants of neural network for tree like data structures?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Consider I have a training set where each data sample is a tree and each node has(including leaf node) its own feature vector. For example, single data sample will look this

[image]

Now I have to classify `leaf` nodes to either of two categories(category_1 or category_2). Can some one please recommend feasible neural network variant for this kind of data.

Comment: You probably want to think about represenations first. For example, if the tree always has the same shape, you could consider reshaping your data to be flat. If not, another idea is to split your trees and train on the classification from one node to the next. If you want to include the information of higher nodes, you can use an LSTM to encode them into a feature vector that represents the current as well as all the higher up nodes and perform classification with that feature vector.

Comment: @GR4 If I train one leaf node at a time, then the feature vector will not have context i.e a leaf node can be classified to some category depends not only based on its ancestors

Comment: If you reshape your data to be flat, all you will have are leaf nodes and each leaf node will have all the information contained in its ancestors too.  In that case, you just have, in your example, nine different collections of information, each associated with some count of observations in category 1 and category 2.

Comment: @jbowman A leaf belongs to category_X  depends also on few properties of all other leaves in the same tree. Lately, I was thinking of implementing a type of sequence to sequence RNN where I input all the leaves and RNN outputs category for all leaves and obviously I have to consider maximum threshold for number of leaves and pad with all zeros if less than that. Do you think this is good idea?

Comment: Do all nodes have a feature vector of the same length? If they do, then I concur an RNN where you first pass in the root, then the child, then the next child, ... then the leaf is a sensible way to go.

Comment: @pvlkmrv all nodes have feature vector of the same length. Can you elaborate bit more. You mean single node becomes single time step?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. The input to the network should just have that dimension, then. I have not worked with RNNs enough to make an exact architecture recommendation, but in principle that should work: It should learn to make its output either category_1 or category_2 after being shown some sequence of steps down the tree.

Comment: Alternatively, should you use a decision tree to learn how to categorize examples? If your tree could handle inputs of variable length, then you could use some kind of combination of all the vectors in a series down to a leaf to classify that leaf. An advantage would be your tree might learn to recover some kind of common structure of training examples and might be more interpretable.

Comment: @pvlkmrv You mean for a decision tree to classify single leaf node I have to pass all nodes feature vector in some order, am I right?

Comment: Decision trees usually take a feature vector of some length all at once for each example. There is no notion of passing in pieces at different time steps.

Comment: @pvlkmrv that means I have to pass node one by one individually. Do you think doing so remembers the context I mean several nodes makes single entity but If pass node one by one there will be no entity

Answer (score 1):

You might be in interested in, in contrast to a *recurrent* neural network, a [*recursive* neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_neural_network), which

> [applies] the same set of weights recursively over a structure, to produce a structured prediction over variable-size input structures, or a scalar prediction on it, by traversing a given structure in topological order ... introduced to learn distributed representations of structure.

You may also be interested in parsing in general, in which tree structures are inferred for sentences, for example.  Each tree structure follows certain rules specified by some grammar.

One paper that might be of interest is aclweb.org/anthology/P/P13/P13-1045.pdf

I have not used them myself, but it appears that there are implementations in pytorch (https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/recursive-neural-networks-pytorch/) and tensorflow  (https://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/06/recursive-neural-networks-tensorflow.html).

Comment: any idea of the library which supports this architecture or should I implement it manually?

Comment: Off the shelf not sure, but I added two links to tutorials for implementing it. @Praveen

Answer (score 0):

There is this paper on [Neural Decision Trees](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.07360). Where the decision tree is the network structure and each node is a perceptron. I also seem to call another paper by researchers in China that made headlines within the last 6 months but what I read about that one was that is was mostly hype.

Comment: I read that paper though it was over the head for me what I understood is, it is to achieve tree structure but not to process tree structure. If I am wrong, it will be a great help if you could write a simple summary of that paper.

Comment: @Praveen It sounds like you are interested in a binary classification problem where your data are a collection of features. The tree is one form of classifier so why would you want to include the tree as a part of the neural net? Did I mis-understand the problem you posted?

Comment: My data structure is in the form of a tree and I want to classify leaf nodes using binary classification. I have to find a way to represent a tree in a flat structure or feed tree itself by doing some kind of tree traversal to the network in such way that leaves don't lose out context.